# Error during make

Tags: compilation, makefile

I am trying to compile my file using make, however, it shows the following error

```
/usr/bin/gcc -march=i586 -m32 -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -nostdlib -c -Wall     -O0 -DBSDURG -DVERSION=\""`cat version`"\" -I../include -o binaries/farm.o ../system/farm.c

Loading object files to produce GRUB bootable xinu
binaries/farm.o: In function `initialize':
farm.c:(.text+0x2c): undefined reference to `malloc'
```

After some searching, people have mentioned that not include "stdlib.h" may be the cause, however, I have included it

```
/*  farm.c  - definition of farmer and vegetarian lab */

#include <xinu.h>
#include "farm.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
```

Anyone some idea what are the possible causes? 
Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`-nostdlib` flag means "don't link with standard C library". `malloc` is libc function. Either you link with libc (by removing `-nostdlib`), or, if that's a requirement, - implement another `malloc` (or don't use this function).

Answer (score 0):

Include files are for compilation time resolution of functions not link time resolution of symbols.

That is a link time issue.

Your problem is most likely caused by the `-nostdlib` since you have told `gcc` not to include any of the normal standard library functions during linking. (It might be `-fono-builtin` but I don't think so.)

You either need to provide your own implementation of whatever standard functions you need (in this case malloc) or manually link with whatever library includes `malloc` (`-lgcc` perhaps?) or drop `-nostdlib` from your compilation and linking line.